# SEM - Analysis of invariance to test regressions

Tags: r, r-lavaan

Let's suppose we have a confirmatory factor analysis CFA with three latent variables **(visual, textual, and speed)** and that we want to add a regression where **speed** is the outcome and **visual** and **textual** are the explanatory variables (that is to say, expand the CFA to a Structural Equation Model SEM).

Also, let's assume that we have the grouping variable **school** (2 categories).
I want to know if the effects (regression paths) of textual and visual are the same for the two groups or if it is better to have different coefficients for every group.

**How can I achieve this?**

My main idea is to follow an analysis of invariance calculating a Weak model, a Scalar model, a Strict model, and finally a model where regression coefficients aer also constrained to be equal across groups. Then, if the *rmsea* and *CFI* for the last model show not major changes I can say that the coefficients can be assumed to be the same; on the contrary, if *rmsea* and *CFI* shows that quality of the model gets worse, it is better to use different estimates for every group.

An alternative would be to make sure the CFA has strict invariance and then add the regression. I could compare the non gruped SEM with the grouped SEM and make a decistion based on the quality of the two models.

```
library(lavaan)

HS.model <- '  visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
               textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
               speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 
               speed ~ textual + visual'

fit <- sem(HS.model, 
           data = HolzingerSwineford1939, 
           group = "school")
summary(fit , standardized = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)

fit.Weak <- sem(model = HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939, 
                group = "school", 
                group.equal = c("loadings"))
summary(fit.Weak  , standardized = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)

fit.Scalar <- sem(model = HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939, 
                group = "school", 
                group.equal = c("loadings", "intercepts")
summary(fit.Scalar  , standardized = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
       
fit.Strict <- sem(model = HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939, 
                   group = "school", 
                   group.equal = c("loadings", "intercepts")
       
fit.Regressors <- sem(model = HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939, 
                       group = "school", 
                       group.equal = c("loadings", "intercepts", "residuals", "regressions")
summary(fit.Regressors  , standardized = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for an anova?

```
> anova(fit, fit.Weak, fit.Strict, fit.Regressors)
Chi-Squared Difference Test

               Df    AIC    BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)    
fit            48 7484.4 7706.8 115.85                                  
fit.Weak       54 7480.6 7680.8 124.04      8.192       6    0.22436    
fit.Strict     60 7508.6 7686.6 164.10     40.059       6  4.435e-07 ***
fit.Regressors 71 7508.5 7645.7 186.00     21.898      11    0.02517 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Tom. I am asking more about the logic of asssessment, so for your response I think that it is ok to constraint the model step by step and evaluate fit, right? Also, I would  like to avoid Chi-Squared test since it has some problems when working with large datasets (more than 1000 observations per group). In that case, what CFI or Rmsea cut-offs should I use?

Comment: Ok. We're leaving the programming part; your question would be better adressed at [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). The proposed `anova` - approach is a comparison of consecutively more constrained models in order to evaluate the additional fit of a more constrained model to a more relaxed model given the number of additional parameters. 1/2

Comment: To save you some time, there is a wide variety of articles discussion "comparative fit" indicees (e.g. CFI and RMSEA; note that CFI is Chi-Square based whereas the baseline model is the maximum relaxed model) and rule of thumbs: [here, my favorit](https://www.guilford.com/books/Principles-and-Practice-of-Structural-Equation-Modeling/Rex-Kline/9781462523344), [researchgate discussion with further literature](https://www.researchgate.net/post/SEM_model_fit_indices). Model fit is deemed good if CFI >= .95 or/and RMSEA <= .05/.06